# how do I connect to sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, database-connection

How do i connect to a sqlite database? I am planning to distribute a db with my application with all the tables already made in it, so i don't need to create a new db or tables, just distribute it.

I so far have experience with mysql where i have used connection strings like

```
<?php session_start();
// DATABASE CONNECTION

$hostname = 'localhost';       
$dbname   = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
$username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
$password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'; 

// Let's connect to host
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
// Select the database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');
?>
```

After the connection is established i go about my business of inserting > selecting > deleting and updating table values using mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array etc.

but how is this process different in SQLITE. all help is appreciated. i am new to sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is a lighter form for sql, it doesn't have a server/client. So you directly "connect" to the file(or inmemory).

You can connect to the memory(which will be flushed after restart of application) by `$db = sqlite3_open(":memory:");` or to a file called "mydatabase.db" with `$db = sqlite3_open("mydatabase.db");`.

More info at http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlite3.php

Comment: But I want all the stored information to remain in the database even after restart, how to prevent a delete of information?